# Which Australian skill assessment is correct for my degree?

Tags: australia, indian-citizens, skilled-migration

I have a Bachelors degree in Computer Science from India and I have 3 years of work experience. Can I have skill assessment through Engineers Australia instead of ACS?

Comment: The assessing authorities are listed by occupation at: https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Work/Work/Skills-assessment-and-assessing-authorities/skilled-occupations-lists/combined-stsol-mltssl

Answer (score 1):

The ACS is the appropriate body to evaluate your skills, as your education and experience would appear to be within Information and Communications Technology (ICT)

> The [ACS ICT](https://www.acs.org.au/msa/information-for-applicants.html) skills assessment will assess if your educational qualifications and work experience are at a professional ICT level and closely related to the nominated occupation (ANZSCO) for migration purposes.

[Engineering Australia](https://www.engineersaustralia.org.au/For-Migrants/Migration-Skills-Assessment) assessment would be for building and engineering professionals, those, for example, with degrees and experience in civil, electrical, mechanical, production, and mining engineering.

Comment: I fall in the same category as the op, do I absolutely need to get all my docs certified from ACS? Or an equivalent authority exists which can do that?